# Updating a property of all the nodes in neo4j db resulted in out of memory

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph db has 3.5 million nodes size of the database is 1.6GB i am trying to update a property for all the nodes via `neo4jshell` with following query.

```
Match (p:Person) set p.regId= toInt(p.regId) ;
```

Before doing this i have added index on Person for property `regId`.
During the execution the following error was thrown

> java.lang.MemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Answer (score 5):

All changes performed by a single Cypher statement are executed in the same transaction. A transaction builds up in memory and gets persisted when you close it.

I guess your transaction here grows to large and therefore resulting in a memory error.

The usual strategy to deal with this is to use `LIMIT` on the cypher statement to have a defined size, report back the number of changes done and run the statement x times until the return value is 0.

In your case:

```
Match (p:Person) 
where p.regId <> toInt(p.regId)
with p limit 10000
set p.regId= toInt(p.regId) 
return count(p)
```

Comment: You usually can do up to a million updates per transaction without too much struggle, just test it out by setting the limit to 1000000.

Comment: I forgot to mention the heap size its 10GB . What would be the expected time given enough memory? few minutes? horus? Query in discussion went for more than 45 mins before running out of memory

Comment: hard to say without the full details like OS, IO subsystem, cache usage.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a description of what's causing the error](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded).  Basically, you're short on memory, an garbage collection isn't finding you any extra free memory.

In the [neo4j performance tuning guide](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/) there's a lot of guidance on how to tweak memory.

The first thing to try is to give your JVM more memory; for the shell you need to set something like `JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` before starting the shell to tweak how much memory the JVM can use, this increases the heap size.

Comment: The max heap size i have set in conf/wrapper-conf.properties is 10GB. It was just using around 4GB when it threw me the error